# Tecnologias para App de mensagens instantâneas

Tags: java, android

Quero desenvolver um app Android(nativo) de mensagens instantâneas como WhatsApp para o meu TCC, gostaria de saber quais tecnologias para a plataforma Java oferecem suporte para esse tipo de comunicação, alguma API etc.

A minha principal dúvida é à respeito da comunicação em tempo real, como ter um canal direto entre dois dispositivos, seria necessário um servidor para intermediar a comunicação?

Pesquisei bastante à respeito e encontrei o padrão XMPP, alguém conhece alguma biblioteca/framework que facilitaria a criação de uma aplicação em Java?

O que preciso é de um guia para criar uma arquitetura correta, desde o servidor até o App.

Comment: Olá Jadson. Bem vindo ao SOpt. A pergunta é justa, mas eu tenho a impressão de que ainda assim ela está um pouquinho ampla pro site. Já leu [ask]? Eu creio que as chances de vc ter respostas melhores aumentariam se você fizesse a pergunta mais específica sobre algum aspecto que você tem dúvida (por exemplo, como criar uma comunicação TCP/IP em Java, ou como enviar uma requisição para um servidor HTTP, algo do tipo).

Comment: Entendi @LuizVieira, obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Existem várias formas de implementar um aplicativo de comunicação. No entanto, vou fazer algumas considerações.

## Tempo real?

Nenhum APP é exatamente em tempo real. Quem usa WhatsApp, Google Hangouts ou Facebook Messenger sabe que muitas vezes a mensagem atrasa.

O que provavelmente você quer é algo que mande as mensagens o mais cedo possível.

## Arquitetura simples

### Mandando a mensagem

Basicamente você precisa que o seu Aplicativo envie a mensagem através de uma requisição HTTP. Isso é simples e basta ver a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html).

Exemplo:

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

### Redirecionando a mensagem

No lado do servidor, você precisa de uma aplicação REST que receba a requisição HTTP com a mensagem. Seria bom você travar isso num banco de dados para registro de histórico e outras funcionalidades.

As tecnologias usadas aqui podem ser:

- Servlets, JAX-RS ou Spring Boot para criar os web services
- JDBC, JDBC Template ou JPA para acesso ao banco

Ao receber a mensagem, sua aplicação deve, por sua vez, fazer uma requisição a uma API como a [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) para fazer o *push* da mensagem para os aparelhos que estejam registrados para recebê-la.

Um exemplo de requisição seria:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

Feito isso, os servidores do Google vão notificar os aparelhos sobre a mensagem.

Para fazer a requisição a esta API você pode usar a biblioteca Apache Http Client.

## Recebendo a mensagem

Finalmente, as mensagens seriam recebidas no(s) aparelho(s) de destino no seguinte método:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
   String message = data.getString("message");
   Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
   Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
   // Handle received message here.
}
```

Claro que é preciso que os aparelhos que irão receber as mensagens tenham o aplicativo e que esse aplicativo se registre para receber as mensagens. Exemplo:

```
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
    }
}
```

## XMPP

Este é um protocolo que possui implementações em Java, mas isso não vai resolver a maior parte dos seus problemas, como o *push* para distribuir as mensagens aos clientes.

Veja [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/177581/1683070) para algumas implementações que você pode usar no lado do servidor.

Entretanto, como disse, você ainda terá que implementar todo o aplicativo e a distribuição de mensagens.

## Considerações

Esta é um exemplo em nível bem alto. Adianto que não é uma tarefa fácil.

Sugiro que você vá criando perguntas específicas sobre cada ponto que tiver dúvidas e evite perguntar de forma tão abrangente sobre a tecnologia. Provavelmente ninguém vai fazer o trabalho todo e postar um passo-a-passo aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Você já ouviu falar em **[Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/examples.html)**?

Creio que seja a sua resposta, é super fácil de utilizar a API.

Inclusive eles tem uma demo:
https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat

Comment: Uso o firebase para este mesmo fim e é fantástico, mas tem limite de conexão, no plano free. Para o caso do @Jadson creio que seja perfeito.

Comment: Olá. Obrigado pela ajuda ao autor da pergunta. O problema é que a sua resposta essenciamente só tem links, e assim ela não é muito boa porque links podem quebrar (e ai a resposta seria inútil para qualquer usuário futuro). Se vc puder editá-la para fornecer ao menos um exemplo de uso (em código), ai vc ganha o meu +1. :) Ou então, diga se gostaria que um moderador convertesse a pergunta em comentário (supondo que vc ainda não tem reputação suficiente para comentar).