# Ajuda entre comunicação entre clientes WEBSERVICE REST - JSON - JAVA

Tags: java, android, json, web-service, rest

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android onde dispositivos podem se comunicar entre si através de mensagens (Mensageiro instantâneo).

Minha aplicação já esta conectando com o Web Service (Desenvolvi ele usando o NetBeans) e o Web service conectando com o banco de dados(MySQL).

Já consigo realizar cadastro de usuário através da aplicação, mandando as informações para o Web service e o Web service realizando o cadastro no banco de dados.

Minha duvida é a seguinte, como eu posso fazer para a minha aplicação enviar uma mensagem para outro usuário, e o usuário receber a mensagem instantemente.

Fazer a mensagem chegar no Web service aparentemente não é difícil, já com as informações também de para qual usuário.

O que não estou conseguindo pensar é como o cliente (Aplicação Android) vai entender que chegou uma mensagem para ele. Como o Web service vai enviar a mensagem para o usuário especificado na mesma.

Uso o JSON para troca de informações.

Comment: se eu não me engano já teve uma pergunta parecida e uma resposta bem legal, vou tentar achar pra vc

Comment: achei, talvez te ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113817/tecnologias-para-app-de-mensagens-instant%C3%A2neas/113867#113867

Comment: uma forma do cliente "entender" e é a que eu costumo ver sendo usada é o cliente continuamente se identificar e "perguntar" para o servidor se existem novas mensagens pra ele, você criou servicos rest, normalmente para mensagens instanteneas são usados sockets para se manter uma unica conexão, com o rest voce vai ter que abrir uma nova conexão toda vez, vai ser mais custoso

Comment: Entendi, vou estudar então sobre sockets, mas você sabe se eu programar através destes sockets, e depois eu quiser desenvolver a mesma aplicação para iOS, seria possivel fazer a conexão também do mesmo ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que desenvolver uma solução eficiente para enviar mensagens do servidor para devices, além de ser particularmente complexo, requer uma estrutura que o http convencional não contempla. Este definitivamente não é o caminho que você precisa seguir, a não ser que você possua alguma estrutura avançada, como o Amazon AWS e muita experiência.

Os fabricantes de devices móveis sabem desta dificuldade e criaram soluções para resolver esta questão sem deixar qualquer desenvolvedor louco. No android nós temos o [GCM (Google Cloud Message)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging), que envia mensagens de até 2kb para o device ou devices especificados.

São muitas etapas para demostrar aqui, mas a lógica é a seguinte.

1. Todo device android por padrão ao se conectar à internet possui uma assinatura única registrada nos servidores google.
2. Quando seu app se registra em seu servidor você registra a assinatura do device
3. De posse da assinatura o seu servidor cria a mensagem (com no máximo 2kb) e envia para os servidores Google GCM
4. Os servidores GCM possuem um acesso direto à todos os devices conectados. Eles portanto enviam a mensagem para o device.
5. O device processa a mensagem que pode ser completa, ou somente um pedido de conexão para baixar informações mais complexas.
6. Se existir a necessidade o device se conecta novamente no seu servidor, para concluir a operação, fazendo um download por exemplo.

Como você pode perceber, são alguns passos necessários. A google oferece toda a [documentação para você](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=pt-br), mas infelizmente não encontrei em português.

Evidentemente existem outras alternativas. Alguns serviços pagos, como o [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) resolvem toda a logística de servidor, mas existe um ônus nisso. Existem também algumas soluções open source que se propões a oferecer estrutura de servidor já adequada às necessidades mobile. Um projeto que pode ter um futuro promissor é o [baasbox](http://www.baasbox.com), mas não sei como ele se comporta em ambiente de produção.

Enfim, espero ter ajudado.